# Downloading OSM data for multiple polygons at one time

Tags: openstreetmap, download

I am interested in the number of buildings found within each protected area in Africa. I have a protected area layer (WGS84) that I am using. The amount of data per protected area will be very small, most likely less than 200 nodes per protected area.

However, I cannot find a GIS tool (either QGIS or ArcGIS) that will allow me to download OSM data for multiple polygons from a vector layer at once, despite the data being very small. I did see that ArcGIS has an option under the OSM editor “Extent of data download” dropbox for intersection or union of inputs but these do not seem to work.

Comment: Does it need to be directly downloaded from OSM?

Comment: I doubt that work but you may try to transform your multiple polygons to one multipart polygon

Answer (score 1):

I use this plug-in in QGIS to download OSM data: [OSMDownloader](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMDownloader/). I don't know if it satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no direct way of downloading in qgis. the [hot export tool](https://export.hotosm.org) has the option to upload a geojson file and download data from it.

Comment: Thanks for the link but that tool still does not allow for more than one polygon's data to be exported at once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more recent option. You could use Geofabrik to download data (e.g. buildings) from your area of interest in *.shp (shapefile) format. It comes directly from OSM. Then just open the file in QGIS.

http://www.geofabrik.de/data/shapefiles.html

> If you need shapefiles for your GIS applications or processes, look no further. Geofabrik produces shapefiles of all kinds. A number of simple shapefiles are available for free on our download server at http://download.geofabrik.de.